# Why can't use "?" operator for a nullable type

Tags: vb.net

I have this line of code

```
Dim result = myStuff.FirstOrDefault(Function (t) t.PrimaryKey = mine.ID?.Value)
```

Right side `ID` is of `Integer?` and left side is always an `integer`.

But this says that cannot resolve .`Value`

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "Right side ID is of Integer? and left side is always an integer." - a [mcve] would really help here. Also, if your question is *just* about VB, please remove the C# tag. (I have no idea whether VB has the null-safe `?.` operator that C# does, or whether it works in the same way that C# does, for example.)

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=`. Atm you're doing an assignment and assigning an `int?` to an `int` is illegal

Comment: Because once you apply the `?` to `int?` you are now dealing with an `int` which does not have a `Value`.   `mine.ID?.Value` implies you want `null` if `mine.ID` is null so just use `mine.ID`.

Comment: @juharr oh so both sides should be nullable for it to work?

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry John, I mean left and right side of the Lambda expression's equality check:  t.PrimaryKey = mine.ID?.Value

Comment: @Knoop, I think that you got fooled by the C# tag, which should not have been there in the first place. The code is VB so there is no `==` operator.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Ah I see, I was fooled indeed:)

Comment: What is the datatype of ID?

Comment: Equality should work when comparing an `int` to a `int?` (false if the `int?` is null) so you don't need to make them match, but it really depends on what you want to happen when `mine.ID` is null.

Comment: I still think a [mcve] would help to clarify this question. I suspect the simplest example wouldn't need a lambda expression, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to extract an `Integer` from an `Integer?` you have to provide a fallback value which will be used in case your `Integer?` is `Nothing`. The method `GetValueOrDefault` does exactly this.

See the following example:

```vb
Dim x As Integer? = 7
Dim y As Integer? = Nothing
Dim z As Integer = 7

Console.WriteLine(If(z = x.GetValueOrDefault(-1), "yes", "no")) ' Prints yes
Console.WriteLine(If(z = y.GetValueOrDefault(-1), "yes", "no")) ' Prints no
```

However, if the only thing you want is to compare an `Integer` to an `Integer?`, there's no need to extract anything. You can compare them directly.

```vb
Dim x As Integer? = 7
Dim y As Integer? = Nothing
Dim z As Integer = 7

Console.WriteLine(If(z = x, "yes", "no")) ' Prints yes
Console.WriteLine(If(z = y, "yes", "no")) ' Prints no
```

The [safe navigation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator) (the one used in your code snippet) will simply resolve to `Nothing` if its operand is also `Nothing`. Doesn't seem to be what you want here.